# Upload file to Amazon S3 using HTTP PUT

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, npm-request

I work in a financial institution and for security reasons my employer cannot give out the `access key id` and the `access key secret` to the AWS account. This means I can't use [aws-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk).

As a next option, would it be possible to upload files using HTTP PUT to a public S3 bucket without using the AWS-SDK that requires the `access key id` and the `access key secret`?

I had a look at this answer: [How to upload a file using a rest client for node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31150447/how-to-upload-a-file-using-a-rest-client-for-node)

And was thinking of this approach:

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
    method: 'PUT',
    preambleCRLF: true,
    postambleCRLF: true,
    uri: 'https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/myFile.pdf',
    multipart: [
        {
            'content-type': 'application/pdf'
            body: fs.createReadStream('/uploads/uploaded-file.pdf') 
        }
    ]
}

request(options, function(err, response, body){

    if(err){
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log('File uploaded to s3');
});
```

Could that work?

Comment: *for security reasons my employer cannot give out the access key id and the access key secret to the AWS account.*  Stop.  This is a seriously flawed premise.  There is no "the" (single) access key/secret.   You can create as many keys and accompanying secrets as you need, each with its own individual permissions.  You can also delegate permissions to keys owned by other  AWS accounts.  Using a publicly writable bucket makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your above code works only if you have custom storage(that too it should be public) and not for AWS storage.

For AWS storage `access key id` and the `access key secret` is mandatory, without these you cannot upload the files to storage

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @Supraj v

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old but for anyone looking for the same you can now use a pre signed url to achieve this, how it works is you create a preSigned url on your server, share it with the client and use this to upload the file to s3

server to generate an url:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  region: 'us-east-1',
  signatureVersion: 'v4'
})
AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'access-key', secretAccessKey: 'access-pass'})

const myBucket = 'clearg-developers'
const myKey = 'directory/newFile.zip'
const signedUrlExpireSeconds = 60 * 5 //seconds the url expires

const url = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', {
    Bucket: myBucket,
    Key: myKey,
    Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds

});
return url
```

and on the client from node you can put to get an empty body:

```
var fileName = '/path/to/file.ext';
var stats = fs.statSync(fileName);
fs.createReadStream(fileName).pipe(request({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: url,
    headers: {
    'Content-Length': stats['size']
}
}, function (err, res, body) {
    console.log('success');
}));
```